# What does the icon with four squares mean?

Tags: battlefield-4

I occasionally get this icon displayed on multiplayer in the top right (just below where the kill log is shown). Does anyone have any idea what it means?

[image: Icon]

Comment: What platform is this on?

Comment: It is PS4. You can deduct the platform from the icon to the left of "BATTLELOG".

Comment: FYI this also happens on PC. Unsure about other platforms.

Comment: @tombull89 It happens on all platforms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It represents packet loss. Check out DICE employee's response [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/battlefield_4/comments/1wk2vl/what_does_this_icon_mean_top_right_of_the_game/cf2rmm0).